# IP whitelisting for admin-interface

Tags: javascript, security

For a huge project, we're going to make a "superadmin" login (all other admin work is directly in frontend) for a place where you can alter a lot of things.

As security is really really important, I've been thinking about only allow people with a certain IP to connect. Does anyone knows of websites that do the same, is it overly protective or can you recommend another really secure way of doing admin-work?
We can make it for a specific browser-only if theres some useful possibilities in Chrome or Firefox.

FYI the frontend is javascript, html and css only

Comment: `another really secure way` precludes you doing it in your frontend Javascript. Do it on the server side.

Comment: Isn't user management a task for the backend, and not the front-end?

Comment: IP blocking in your javascript is not very useful, someone could just alter the value... For security, you *need* to make your backend verify and restrict everything, not your frontend js.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: adminwork can be much more than user management ;)

Comment: @gpgekko: maybe this could be inserted into the .htaccess-file?

Comment: Perhaps ask the guys over at http://security.stackexchange.com/ for tips...

Comment: I wasn't just talking about "user management". I was talking about user management as part of the system that should belong to the backend.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Why should it belong to the backend?

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is using `CORS` and another login to make the current `IP`  A N D  `port` known and allowing cross domain access only for that!

Answer (score 1):

It won't make sense to do it client-side, since there isn't really anything stopping an attacker from modifying/disabling your JS.

So only **secure** option is server-side. I've done so myself with a CMS system in PHP.

**UPDATE: Sample Implementation**

In that project, I used a GeoIP-service (like [this one](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) from MaxMind)

```
function geoIPRequest($ip){
    $params = getopt('l:i:');

    if (!isset($params['l'])) $params['l'] = '<userIDtoMaxMind>';
    if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = $ip;

    $query = 'https://geoip.maxmind.com/a?' . http_build_query($params);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $query,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'MaxMind PHP',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        )
    );

    $countryCode = curl_exec($curl);

    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        throw new Exception(
            'GeoIP request failed with a curl_errno of '
            . curl_errno($curl)
        );
    }
    return $countryCode;
}

$countryCode = geoIPRequest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if(!in_array($countryCode, array('DE', 'DK', 'EU', 'GB', 'SE'))){
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    echo "You don't have access";
    exit();
}
```

*The code above is adapted from the sample code on MaxMind's website*

You'd of course need to adapt it to your use-case. For me specific countries were good enough. If you need to whitelist *specific* IPs, I'd advised you to create a database table with whitelisted IPs that you then query when someone requests your admin-page.

Comment: Interesting. How did you do it?

Comment: @MortenHjort I've added a full sample to my answer. Keep in mind that I've simplified it a bit for clarity. You might want to consider caching results from the GeoIP-service you use for instance.

Comment: How does it fare when someone uses a proxy/VPN which happens to be in the same area? Or when the third-party service goes down? It can cripple the system.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Indeed. You're correct. I'm not in any way claiming that GeoIP-blocking is fool proof. In my specific case, however, it was adequate to keep automated hacker bots out. To better accommodate users while staying secure, some sort of certificate-based solution would be far superior (but that's rather advanced, IMO - and not what OP asked). Also, I have a backup in place *and* utilise caching to counter potential third-party downtime.

Answer (score 1):

It can be good protection, if you can be assured that all "superadmins" will have static IP address, and will not be unable to use application because their IP changed in the middle of the night.

Other method, similar to the one you mentioned, is VPN, where users after connecting to VPN would have an IP address from your private pool, and your application would accept connections only from that pool (even better, you can make apache/nginx vhost for the superadmin application listen only on VPN ip).

Another positive side of the VPN approoach, is that you are securing the traffic too, apart from filtering access.

Comment: Hmm I might be able to place this "superadmin-login" inside a VPN, but that would get issues if a user wants to login to it from home wouldnt it? What about using Mac-addresses? It will be only max 4 people who will access this place.

Comment: VPN connection can be made from anywhere, user would only need to set up VPN connection on their home computer. It is largely similar to dial-up connection (when speaking about setup), so user can connect from everywhere (even from iPhone and alike), assuming that VPN ports are open on your server-side network (routers, firewalls, etc.) and that vpn-passthrough is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask the server-people about this!

Comment: Also, blocking access from this on the client-side is not an option and you should not even consider it (as pointed in other answers). If you want to be secure (and I think you do, based on your question), this access filter should be implemented on server side.

Answer (score 1):

i have to say, this doesn't sound like a awesome idea

any real security traditionally requires a server component, would recommend the following :

a) make all login pages served over https

b) include a server tech such as ruby/php to do the following:

digest authentication -> 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

which is basically

login details stored in a db (make sure you only store password hashes + salt in db!!!)

php/ruby compared login details to db log in details

once authenticated store this authenticate state as a digest cookie

see here for php implementation : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

but seriously please please don't use client implemented security, it's a bad bad idea

for more security concerns and ideas to watch out for see here ->

http://w3af.org/

http://w3af.org/understanding-html5-security

also very good resource for learning about how amazingly evil and good hackers are, and how to thwart their plans

http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/owasp good books on common security flaws (may be free pdfs online)

Comment: Thanks! I think I didnt write it clearly enought, but I never said I needed to have this secure-adminsite clientside. I only meant that the public frontend was in BackboneJS-code and therefore clientside.

Comment: Lol ah....
i think we all got a bit worried there, good luck with you project :)